# Making my identity 2.0 custom extension method thread safe

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5

So I created a class to hold user settings and i'm saving it as a JSON string so that I can modify it whenever I please without doing migrations every time I add one setting.

Anyways everything is working wonderful, well until, exception, I look further into it, and I've found things about it being thread safe but I don't really understand what they mean, how is my simple function that accesses entity identity dbcontext, not thread safe?

```
    public static AppUserSettings GetUserSettings(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var user = IdentityDbContext.Users.Find(identity.GetUserId());
        return user.SettingsClass != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppUserSettings>(user.SettingsClass) : new AppUserSettings();
    }
```

and the sister function:

```
    public static void SetUserSettings(this IIdentity identity, AppUserSettings toSaveUserSettings)
    {
        var user = IdentityDbContext.Users.Find(identity.GetUserId());
        user.SettingsClass = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toSaveUserSettings);
        DatabaseUtil.SaveChanges(IdentityDbContext);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, if need be I can attach other classes and/or snippets, but I feel like it is largely a Identity/Entity issue.

Comment: What's the point of passing `this IIdentity identity` argument to both methods if both don't even use it?

Comment: That is so blatantly obvious after you pointed it out, passing the context is pointless when your already passing the identity, I'll update the code. I still don't think this method is thread safe with those changes though, but it does simplify it.

Comment: As long as the db context is per thread/request, I don't see any issues.

Comment: I'm wonder if it is possible the issue I was having was caused by calling identity.GetUserId() two times in the original code. `return _identityDbContext.Users.Find(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()).SettingsClass != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppUserSettings>(_identityDbContext.Users.Find(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()).SettingsClass) : new AppUserSettings();` That was the orginal code that was causing exceptions.

Comment: Do you have the exact exception message and the line that caused it?